# What's the right way to use the Factory method design pattern?

Tags: factory-pattern, design-patterns

[image]

The diagram above taken from the **factory method** example, the cross at the right corner indicate it's not the right solution. So I came up with my own:

Runner.java

```
package test;

public class Runner {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fighter f = new Fighter();
        f.attack();
        Wizard w = new Wizard();
        w.attack();
    }

}
```

Player.java

```
package test;

public abstract class Player {
    protected String type;

    public Player(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void attack() {
        WeaponFactory.getWeapon(type).hit();
    }
}
```

Fighter.java

```
package test;

public class Fighter extends Player {

    public Fighter() {
        super("Fighter");
    }

}
```

Wizard.java

package test;

```
public class Sword implements Weapon {

    public Sword() {
    }

    public void hit() {
        System.out.println("Hit by sword");
    }

}
```

Weapon.java

```
package test;

public abstract class Weapon {

    public void hit(){};

}
```

Wand.java

package test;

```
public class Wand extends Weapon {

    public Wand() {
    }

    public void hit() {
        System.out.println("Hit by Wand");
    }

}
```

Sword.java

package test;

```
public class Sword extends Weapon {

    public Sword() {
    }

    public void hit() {
        System.out.println("Hit by sword");
    }

}
```

WeaponFactory.java

package test;

```
public class WeaponFactory {


    public static Weapon getWeapon(String type) {
        Weapon returnValue = null;
        if(type.equals("Wizard")) {
            returnValue = new Wand();
        }else if(type.equals("Fighter")) {
            returnValue = new Sword();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

Did I do it right in term of using the **Factory method** design pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WeaponFactory violates the Open-Closed Principle. To be compliant with object oriented design, consider following changes:

```
public abstract class Player {
    protected WeaponFactory weaponFactory;

    public Player(WeaponFactory weaponFactory) {
        this.weaponFactory = weaponFactory;
    }
    public void attack() {
        weaponFactory.getWeapon().hit();
    }
}

public class Fighter extends Player {
    public Fighter() {
        super(new SwordFactory());
    }
}

public interface WeaponFactory {
    Weapon getWeapon();
}
```

Create SwordFactory and WandFactory implementing WeaponFactory.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code. Your code is much better. But I just want to how my code violates the Open-Closed Principle

Comment: @yozloy Comparing types at runtime often results in violating Open Closed Principle. (And probably that's what got you uncomfortable with this design.) If you wanted to introduce a new kind of player, you would be forced to modify the WeaponFactory (so WeaponFactory is not closed for modifications). In the proposed design if you introduce a new player, you can create a new factory, so you _add new code and don't change old code_. [More about OCP with similar case of type comparisons](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Checking out this [link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/factory-pattern.html) I think your code is ok.

Though you could simply return the new object in Weapon Factory.

```
public class WeaponFactory {


    public static Weapon getWeapon(String type) {

        if(type.equals("Wizard")) {
            return new Wand();
        }else if(type.equals("Fighter")) {
            return new Sword();
        }

    }

}
```